# Asp.net MVC - Can I load a view from a different view folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my app I have a need to load the same view from two different controllers without placing the view in the shared views directory.

Basically I have this folder structure

- Controllers

  - EventsController.cs
  - SearchController.cs
- Views

  - Events

    - Preview.aspx
  - Search

basically picture it much the same as here on stack overflow.  You get a preview of a bunch of questions under the questions link, but you also get an identically formatted page when you do a search in the search bar.  The views and viewmodels are presumably identical.

Since the view I need for search is exactly the same as the view I need for events, I'd like to reuse the same view. I would however like to avoid using the shared directory for this specific view.

So my two part question is ---

1. Is this possible, and if so how?
2. Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Simply `return View("~/Views/Events/Preview.aspx")`.

However, i would advise against it for a number of reasons.  The biggest being that this will be non-obvious to anyone trying to modify the code later (maybe even you) and might lead to potential errors.

A better approach might be to create a "Shared" view, or a shared partial view.  My preference would be a shared partial view, then in your non-shared view render the partial view functionality you want.

Comment: If I go with this approach, it will be that I have identical views in the Events folder and the Search folder, which isn't a deal breaker, just trying to keep it DRY. I don't need a partial view that renders everything in the view, that would just be weird.

Comment: But are you really rendering everything in the view?  If nothing else, wouldn't the title be different?  I'd also suggest that if it's really the exact same page, why not just use a child action to call the other page?

Comment: You're right, I could very well call it `Events/Search` and keep it in the same controller. Because yes it's all very much identical. The title is dynamic, as it is with all of my views, and is generated in the ViewModel.

Comment: This answer is not correct. `return View(someSpecificViewString)` causes a 404. I was extremely careful to make sure the specified path and cshtml  file exists, yet MVC still pretends it doesn't.

Comment: @FireWingLead - The answer is correct, you are obviously doing something wrong, but it's impossible to tell since you just said "somestring" rather than giving us your exact code.  For instance, are you passing an actual string?  Or a dynamic?  or a string that was cast to an object?  there are many ways this can back fire on you.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - I eventually figured out why this didn't work for me on my own. It was a pain in the butt, and more complicated than I have space for here. Sorry if my last comment sounded disrespectful--it was meant in no other way than a simple "this is my discoveries after trying it myself" sort of report. I did not make it lightly, or without exploring possibilities extensively. Also, I said "someString" because I had tried lots of different strings and approaches, and it was the concept--not any specific approach I had tried--that was important to the comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's possible.
2. I am not sure if you are using strong-typed views. But suppose it is, then it is a bit weird for me that you have Event search & Search with same View Model. Possibly separate them with two different view models and view would be better IMHO. Moreover, if you specify the name of view to load in controller, it is somehow considered to be coupling view and controller and it certainly not a good idea.

Comment: The search function ONLY searches events, so the results are formatted exactly the same as events. The view model is exactly the same, and the only "subtle" difference is that the search controller has a `q` parameter (for query).

Comment: maybe you should abstract the display into an control then and reuse that instead.