# Redirect to view in other folder

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

Can I create a redirect to view in another folde, by calling a webapi controller in MVC method?

I need a simple solution/method to call. I will refactor the rest later..

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551404/asp-net-mvc-can-i-load-a-view-from-a-different-view-folder

Comment: View dosent exist in the ApiController. Im looking for a simple workaround until im finish rebuild the views in the project.